# Show formatted text via CKEditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, textarea, editor

sorry the question is a bit trivial, but I'm using CKeditor 4 for my form, I set it perfectly, the toolbar for bold, lowercase etc. is then shown correctly.

My question is, once I have saved the text sent by this form in the database, I need to take it obviously formatted (for example bold) but the text is displayed compact and with code such as  raw.

How can I print formatted text? I didn't find anything clear to do this in the guide. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/htmlformatting.html#editor1
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_output_format.html
This is what you can do from CKEditor point of view.

Please note however that you are submitting that HTML to server and then save it into data base - this is beyond editor control and most likely where formatting gets destroyed. I would recommend putting some break-points in your server code and debug it to check where exactly formatting gets removed.